# Define Folder to save Images

Tags: images

The Plugin save the Images to /PLUGINNAME/images but i want that it moves to /uploads

The Code inside the Plugin is this here

```
define('WPR_URLPATH', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.plugin_basename( dirname(__FILE__) ).'/' );
$wpr_saveurl = WPR_URLPATH . "images";
$wpr_cache = ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/". plugin_basename( dirname(__FILE__) )."/images";
```

How can I define to save the Images there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "the plugin"?

Anyhow , you need to change `WP_PLUGIN_URL` to `wp_upload_dir` in your `define`.

You can read more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir